# Sumar filas de matriz utilizando threads

Tags: java

Estoy muy perdido con el tema de hilos, necesito sumas las filas de una matriz utilizando hilos, alguna orientacion como puedo realizar este proceso?

Por ejemplo esta matriz:

```
    /**
 *
 * @author Juanfrancisco
 */
public class SumaFilas {
     private int [][] matriz;
    private int total;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    private int fila;
    public SumaFilas() {
        //constructor que rellena la matriz con numeros aleatroiros de 0 a 10
          matriz=new int[3][3];
          Random rd =new Random();
          for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
              for(int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++){
                    matriz[i][j]=rd.nextInt(10);

              }

          }
    }


   //metodo para que instancia cada hilo y sume 
    public void sumar(){


        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
            this.fila=i;//para saber por la fila que va
             Thread t=new Thread(new Suma());//instanciar la clase que hereda de thread

        t.start();
//es importante dormir el hilo ..el argumento son los segundos ...
         try {
             Thread.sleep(400);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(SumaFilas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

        }

    }
//Simplemente que muestre la matriz por consola
    public void mostrar(){
        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++){
                 System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }

     class Suma extends Thread{
          /**
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void run(){
           System.out.println("Hilo en ejecucion "+getName());


                System.out.println("FILA "+fila);
               for(int j=0;j<matriz[fila].length;j++){
              System.out.print(" Valor a sumar "+matriz[fila][j]);
              total+=matriz[fila][j];

             }
               System.out.println(" Total "+total);

          System.out.println(" ");

    }
     }

}
```

el main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    SumaFilas s=new SumaFilas();
    s.mostrar();
    s.sumar();
    System.out.println(s.getTotal());

}
```

Comment: sabes que una regunta asi sin algun planteamiento y basada en opiniones termia cerrada.. no?

Comment: gracias edite la pregunta

Comment: Y tu problema???

Comment: sumar cada fila utilizando hilos.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema con tu código? Veo que ya tienes como sumar cada fila utilizando hilos, pero cual es el problema?

Comment: En estas lineas me aparece el siguiente error:
         try {
             Thread.sleep(400);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(SumaFilas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

error: cannot find symbol
             Logger.getLogger(SumaFilas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

rror: cannot find symbol
             Logger.getLogger(SumaFilas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

Comment: Estás haciendo trampa poniendo el hilo a dormir. Además el hecho de hacer eso convierte tu problema de concurrencia en un problema secuencial "solucionado" con hilos. Te recomiendo agregarle el atributo `fila` a la clase `Suma` para que en el constructor le pases el índice de la fila que debe resolver. También crear una variable local dentro del método `run` para que lleve la suma total de la fila que le tocó, si la dejas global se van a acumular las sumas de todos los hilos.

Comment: ¿Eso de Logger.getLogger(SumaFilas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);   te lo puso el IDE?

Answer (score 0):

He visto solo un fallo. El total, debería estar también en la clase Suma, así, cada hilo tendrá su propio total. Éste total, se lo devolvemos a la clase SumaFila para que desde el main puedas hacer un getTotal().

Por otra parte, para asegurarnos de que un hilo no empiece hasta que el anterior haya terminado, se puede utilizar el método hilo.join().

```
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class SumaFilas {

    private int[][] matriz;

    private int total;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    private int fila;

    public SumaFilas() {
        // constructor que rellena la matriz con numeros aleatroiros de 0 a 10
        matriz = new int[3][3];
        Random rd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = rd.nextInt(10);


            }

        }
    }

    // metodo para que instancia cada hilo y sume
    public void sumar() {

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            this.fila = i;// para saber por la fila que va
            Suma suma = new Suma();
            Thread t = new Thread(suma);// instanciar la clase que hereda de thread

            t.start();
            try {
                t.join(); //esperamos a que el hilo termine
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //recuperamos el total del hilo y lo guardamos en el total de la clase
            //para mostrarlo en el main.
            total += suma.getTotal();

        }

    }

//Simplemente que muestre la matriz por consola
    public void mostrar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }

    class Suma extends Thread {

        /*
         * Añadimos el atributo total, para cada hilo.
         */
        private int total;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hilo en ejecucion " + getName());

            System.out.println("FILA " + fila);
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[fila].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" Valor a sumar " + matriz[fila][j]);
                total += matriz[fila][j];

            }
            System.out.println(" Total " + total);

            System.out.println(" ");

        }

        /**
         * Creamos un método que devuelva el total de la suma
         * @return int
         */
        public int getTotal() {
            return total;
        }
    }

}
```

Por otro lado el main se quedaría igual:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumaFilas s=new SumaFilas();
        s.mostrar();
        s.sumar();
        System.out.println(s.getTotal());

}
```

Resultado:

```
3 7 3 
8 8 6 
2 5 2 
Hilo en ejecucion Thread-0
FILA 0
 Valor a sumar 3 Valor a sumar 7 Valor a sumar 3 Total 13

Hilo en ejecucion Thread-2
FILA 1
 Valor a sumar 8 Valor a sumar 8 Valor a sumar 6 Total 22

Hilo en ejecucion Thread-4
FILA 2
 Valor a sumar 2 Valor a sumar 5 Valor a sumar 2 Total 9

44
```

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.